# How can I write np.linalg.norm as an sql function?

Tags: python, sql, numpy, math, vector

I have a database and I need to use a function similar to the `np.linalg.norm` function on this database, so how can I write an SQL function for it? or what are the alternative solutions?

Thanks you

Comment: What do you have in the database ? Do you want to calculate norm of what ?

Comment: Iam use Postgres, I have cube data type of 128 dimensional array, in the table I separated the 128 array to 2 columns, each column has 64 element, I need to write function to calculate norm of this dimensional and another given dimensional.

sample: `norm( array1 - array2 )`


let array1 from row x, and array2 from row y.

Comment: How do you select the rows ? Does each row has some sort of id ?

Comment: Yes, each row has a unique id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you clarified in the comments, you are using cube data type to store your arrays.

First of all, you need to allow a 128 dimensional array in a single column entry. As described in item F.9.5 of the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/cube.html), to do that you need to modify the macro in the header file `cubedata.h` to allow dimensions bigger than 100.

Assuming the norm you are considering is an euclidian one, you can use the `cube <-> cube → float8` operator for the norm (item F.9.3 of the docs).

For example, the nearest neighbor of the 3-D point `(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)` could be found efficiently with:

```
SELECT c FROM test ORDER BY c <-> cube(array[0.5,0.5,0.5]) LIMIT 1;
```

Source: the [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/cube.html).